# SDL traces after moving image

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a problem with moving images in SDL with c++. After moving the picture, a trace is drawn behind it.

```
SDL_Surface * image = IMG_Load("Images/img.jpg");
SDL_Texture * img = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image);
SDL_QueryTexture(img, NULL, NULL, &texW, &texH);
```

And here in the loop moving

```
for (long i = 0; i < 3000.0; i+=2)
{
    if (i < 900)
    {
        SDL_QueryTexture(img, NULL, NULL, &texW, &texH);
        SDL_Rect dstrectFornt = { 400, res_y-i, texW, texH };
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, front, NULL, &dstrectFornt);
        SDL_FillRect(image, NULL, 0x000000);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you clearing the window before each image render?

Comment: I do something like that SDL_RenderClear(renderer);. I do it before first part of code.

Comment: You should call it each frame right before rendering the image. It shoud be in your `draw()` function

Comment: Can you show me an example of how I can do it?

Comment: Checkout the source code of this [LazyFoo tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/07_texture_loading_and_rendering/index.php). Note that he is calling the `SDL_RenderClear()` each frame in `while` loop.

Comment: Okay, but SDL_RenderClear cleans everything. As on the screen I have many other elements and I want to move only one.

Comment: each frame you should clear the whole screen and rerender everything again

Comment: But then there is a terrible low fps.

Comment: This is how all games do it, 2D and 3D. If you have low FPS something else is the issue. But my guess is that you haven't even measured its performance. Just try it my way and see for yourself. If you're not drawing milions of objects, you will easily have FPS in thousands.

Comment: @sjaustirni You could also use a hierarchy of intermediate textures (for stuff that might not change that often, for example menus) and render copy that instead of all independent textures again.

Comment: @Aram, true, GUI-heavy applications usually render only parts of the screen that have actually changed. But I believe it's better not to complicate things for beginners and only introduce them to the basic idea upon which they can later build.